# Error parsing dacpac docker microsoft sql server

Tags: .net, sql-server, docker, dockerfile, dacpac

I am trying to create an image with a file dockerfile and using dacpac, but when I try do publish, it throw this exception: Error parsing connection string: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacProfile' threw an exception..
This is my dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express

COPY sqlpackage/1033 /opt/sqlpackage/1033
COPY sqlpackage/Extensions /opt/sqlpackage/Extensions
COPY sqlpackage/en /opt/sqlpackage/en
COPY sqlpackage/DacUnpack.exe /opt/sqlpackage/DacUnpack.exe
COPY sqlpackage/Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.dll/ /opt/sqlpackage/Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.dll
COPY sqlpackage/Microsoft.Data.Tools.Utilities.dll /opt/sqlpackage/Microsoft.Data.Tools.Utilities.dll
COPY sqlpackage/Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll /opt/sqlpackage/Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll
COPY sqlpackage/Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Extensions.dll /opt/sqlpackage/Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Extensions.dll
COPY sqlpackage/Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Extensions.xml /opt/sqlpackage/Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Extensions.xml
COPY sqlpackage/SqlPackage.exe /opt/sqlpackage/SqlPackage.exe
COPY sqlpackage/SqlPackage.exe.config /opt/sqlpackage/SqlPackage.exe.config

COPY ./HAS_Database /tmp/HAS_Database

ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
ENV SA_PASSWORD=PaSSw0rd

RUN /opt/sqlpackage/sqlpackage /a:Publish /pr:'/tmp/HAS_Database/has.aux.ddbb.dev.publish.xml' /sf:'/tmp/HAS_Database/has.aux.ddbb.dacpac'
```

This is my publish file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IncludeCompositeObjects>True</IncludeCompositeObjects>
    <TargetDatabaseName>HAS_ME_AUX_DEV_DEPLOY</TargetDatabaseName>
    <ScriptDatabaseOptions>False</ScriptDatabaseOptions>
    <BlockOnPossibleDataLoss>False</BlockOnPossibleDataLoss>
    <DropIndexesNotInSource>True</DropIndexesNotInSource>
    <DropExtendedPropertiesNotInSource>True</DropExtendedPropertiesNotInSource>
    <ProfileVersionNumber>1</ProfileVersionNumber>
    <BlockWhenDriftDetected>False</BlockWhenDriftDetected>
    <RegisterDataTierApplication>True</RegisterDataTierApplication>
    <TargetConnectionString>Data Source=.;Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Pooling=False;Context Connection=False;Password=PaSSw0rd</TargetConnectionString>
    <VerifyDeployment>False</VerifyDeployment>
    <VerifyCollationCompatibility>False</VerifyCollationCompatibility>
    <ScriptRefreshModule>False</ScriptRefreshModule>
    <ScriptNewConstraintValidation>False</ScriptNewConstraintValidation>
    <PopulateFilesOnFileGroups>False</PopulateFilesOnFileGroups>
    <DisableAndReenableDdlTriggers>True</DisableAndReenableDdlTriggers>
    <DoNotAlterChangeDataCaptureObjects>True</DoNotAlterChangeDataCaptureObjects>
    <DropStatisticsNotInSource>False</DropStatisticsNotInSource>
    <DeployScriptFileName>publish_dev.sql</DeployScriptFileName>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The source sqlpackage binary paths in your dockerfile look suspect. Download the [Windows .NET Core zip file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage-download?view=sql-server-ver15), extract to a directory named sqlpackage in your build context directory, and copy that directory into your container for use in the build.

Below is an example dockerfile that works for me:

```
FROM microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express

COPY ./sqlpackage /opt/sqlpackage/
COPY ./HAS_Database /tmp/HAS_Database

ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
ENV SA_PASSWORD=PaSSw0rd

RUN /opt/sqlpackage/sqlpackage /a:Publish /pr:'/tmp/HAS_Database/has.aux.ddbb.dev.publish.xml' /sf:'/tmp/HAS_Database/has.aux.ddbb.dacpac'
```